# Export long org-mode file in multiple "\input"ted .tex files

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

Let's say I have a very long org-mode file `main.org` with 100 top-level headlines:

```
* H1
  text
* H2
  text 
...
* H100
  text
```

I'd like to export main.org into

- 100 .tex files `H<n>.tex` (1<=n<=100) --or with other filenames-- one for each headline with its corresponding text content,
- plus one master file `main.tex` (with a preamble) and 100 inputs `\input{H<n>}` (1<=n<=100)

Icing on the cake: any export would update `H<k>.tex` only if a modification of the corresponding headline H was detected in `main.org`.

Would this be doable?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own LaTeX export backend derived from `latex`.

That is quite easy because you can inherit almost everything from `latex`.

The only thing that you need to overwrite is `org-latex-headline`.

In your own `org+-latex-export-to-latex` you define the section
counter and the file name base for the exported files.

Here is how this looks like:

```el
(require 'ox-latex)

(org-export-define-derived-backend 'latexfiles
    'latex
  :translate-alist '((headline . org+-latex-headline))
  :menu-entry
  '(?L "Export to LaTeX files"
       org+-latex-export-to-latex)
  )

(defun org+-latex-headline (headline contents info)
  "Write CONTENTS into section file and return input statement.
Extract headline level from SECTION.
Get file name base and section number from INFO."
  (let* ((level (org-element-property :level headline)))
    (cl-assert (numberp level) "Expected headline level")
    (setq contents (org-latex-headline headline contents info))
    (if (> level 1)
    contents
      (let ((num (plist-get info 'top-header-counter)))
    (cl-assert (numberp num) "Cannot get section number")
    (plist-put info 'top-header-counter (incf num))
    (let ((fn (format "%s-%0.3d.tex" (plist-get info 'file-name-base) num)))
      (with-temp-file fn
        (insert contents))
      (format "\\input{%s}\n" fn))))))

(defun org+-latex-export-to-latex
    (&optional async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)
  "Export to \"main.tex\" and section files."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((fn-base (org-export-output-file-name "" subtreep))
     (outfile (concat fn-base ".tex"))
     (ext-plist (append
             `(top-header-counter 0
               file-name-base ,fn-base)
             ext-plist)))
    (org-export-to-file 'latexfiles outfile
      async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist)))

(provide 'org+-latex)
;;; org+-latex.el ends here
```

Put this stuff into a file `org+-latex.el` within your loadpath and require it in your init file.

There is a new menu item `[L] Export to LaTeX files` in the Org export dialog window which you can use to export the top level sections to separate files.

Comment: This is wonderful and clear, thank you. I'm going to implement this, replacing ``\input`` by ``\include``so that I'll be able to add ``\includeonly``in my preamble to select only specific headlines to be compiled, while keeping all references and page number unchanged, as explained here https://latexref.xyz/_005cinclude-_0026-_005cincludeonly.html